# (Help) Code To Find in a given string of numbers

Tags: python

> Ramanujan is so fond of playing number games. One day Ramanujan and
>   Anish played a game. Ramanujan gave Anish a number string and asked
>   him to find all the distinct substrings of size at most six that are
>   prime. Anish being good at maths takes up the game and if he can give
>   solutions to all the input sets Ramanujan provides him, Anish wins the
>   game. Your task is to help Anish win the game.
>
> **Input Format:**
>
> First line contains T, The number of test cases. Each test case
>   contains a string of size N containing only integers.
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> 1 <= Number of Test Cases <= 10
>
> 1 <= N <= 10^7

Code:

```
def prime(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if num%i==0:
                return False
        else :
            return True
    else:
        return False

def get_all_substrings(string):
    length = len(string)
    alist = []
    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(i,length):
            alist.append(string[i:j + 1])
    for i in range(length, -1, -1):
        for j in range(length, i, -1):
            alist.append(string[i:j + 1])
    return list(set(alist))


t = int(input())
for i in range(1, t+1):
    a = list(map(int, get_all_substrings(input().strip())))
    prime_count = 0
    for i in a:
        if len(str(i))>6:
            a.remove(i)
    a.sort()
##    print(a)
##    for i in a:
##        print(i, " : " , prime(i))
    for i in a:
        if prime(i):
            prime_count +=1
    print(prime_count)
```

This outputs the correct values as per my custom tests. You can also print the respective list and its prime Boolean equivalent.

**Problem**: I got a timeout on all my results.

What and where exactly is the problem?

Comment: Is this a problem from code wars or something? If you get the right results but time out, it's because your program is correct but too slow. You'll need to come up with ways to speed it up, or maybe even a different algorithm entirely.

Comment: what would be your approach..?

Answer (score 2):

Besides @Prune's mathematical improvements, there are a few other programming improvements.

First, there is no need in `get_all_substrings()` for `alist` to ever actually be a list and not just a set It doesn't even need to be changed at the end. Use `.add()` instead of `.append()`.

Second, you can save time in the construction of your list `a` in a of couple ways:

- Unless I'm mistaken, it shouldn't need to be sorted. Although sorting it may help if you're using @Prune's suggesting of storing already found primes.
- We can turn the substrings into integers as soon as they are calculated. So we would have something like `alist.add(int(string[i:j + 1]))`. This saves memory and also will make it easy to compare to see if they are too long. Since we know the maximum value of a 9-digit number (in base 10), we can simply check to see if it is larger, which is very fast. `i > 999999`
- Don't add the entries that are too long in the first place. There is a nice, Pythonic way to do this. We can use a *conditional list comprehension*.

List comprehensions look like this:

```
>>> my_list = [i for i in range(10)]
>>> print(my_list)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

A condition can be added so that only the elements we want are added:

```
>>> my_list = [i for i in range(10) if i%2 == 0]
>>> print(my_list)
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

This is equivalent to the following:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(10):
    if i%2 == 0:
        my_list.append(i)
```

So putting that together, we can generate a with just one line:

```
a = [val for val in get_all_substrings(input().strip) if val > 999999]
```

I expect you could do even better by not generating those too-long substrings at all, and avoiding creating duplicates as well, which would remove the need for a set.

Comment: thank you this have given me an idea over code optimization and i hope to apply them even better in future codes

Answer (score 1):

You're failing the time limit.  On my Xeon-based system, your `prime` function can handle primes around 10^6 at only about 8 per second.  Since you have to process lists up to 10^7 integers, this would take on the order of 2 weeks with such primes.  In short, you need to research faster ways of determining whether a number is prime.

First of all, there are two straightforward restrictions that will speed this up a *lot*:

1. Divide by only primes.  If a number is divisible by 4, you already noted that it's divisible by 2.  To determine that 289 is not a prime, there's no need to test against 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, ...
2. Stop looking for factors at the number's square root.  Any factor larger than the sqrt *must* have a cognate less than the sqrt.

You can find these two tests implemented with a simple browser search.

Beyond this, you can speed up a lot by maintaining a list of primes.  First, use them for divisors; second, test for inclusion in the list.  For the input you get, is there any sense to memoize newly-found primes?

If you want a little more speed and sophistication, look up an implementation of the Rabin-Miller algorithm for fast prime detection.  It's "only" probabilistic, but has been shown to have 100% accuracy with k=7 (quantity of checks) for 128-bit integers.

Comment: thank you so much you cleared a lot of my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to make your code faster. For example a speed-up for your `prime` function would be:

```
def isPrimeX(n):
    if n in [2,3]: return True
    if n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0: return False
    needCheckTill = int(math.sqrt(n))
    for i in range(6, needCheckTill+2, 6):
        if n % (i-1) == 0 or n % (i+1) == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

In order to test for a prim number, you don't need to check every number against this number. In fact it is sufficient to check only prim numbers till the square root of possible number. The above code also takes advantage of the fact, that all prim numbers > 3 can be written in the form 6n ± 1 (see  https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/six.html).

With this in mind, you may see another speedup. We can cache the prim numbers from 1 till sqrt(10E7) and use the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm in order to calculate them:

```
# get a list of all prim numbers between 1 and 10E7
import math

def isPrim(n, belowPrims):
    limit = int(math.sqrt(n))
    for prim in belowPrims:
        if prim > limit: break
        if n % prim == 0: return False 
    return True

def calcPrims():
    yield 2
    yield 3
    toTest, nextN = [], 6
    while True:
        p1 = nextN - 1
        if isPrim(p1, toTest):
            yield p1
            toTest.append(p1)
        p2 = nextN + 1
        if isPrim(p2, toTest):
            yield p2
            toTest.append(p2)
        nextN += 6

limit = int(math.sqrt(10 ** 7)) + 1 
listOfPrims = []
for prim in calcPrims():
    if prim > limit:
        break
    listOfPrims.append(prim)
```

The rest of your code can also get further optimized!

Comment: thank you, this was really helpful sir..

Comment: @Dbug On stackoverflow "thank you" is accepting + upvoting the answer ;)

Comment: but you're welcome nevertheless ;)